# processing a form without refreshing the page using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which I want to submit without refreshing the whole page.
I've found a ready source code and implemented it on my pages, but it refuses to work!

here is the html form I need to submit:

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="actionForm" id="actionForm" class="actionForm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="adID" value="'.$row['adID'].'" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="adStatus" value="'.$row['adStatus'].'" />
                    <input type="submit" name="editAd" value="ערוך מודעה" class="actionButtons" />
                    <input type="submit" name="upgradeAd" value="הקפץ מודעה" class="actionButtons" />
                    <input type="submit" name="changeAdStatus" class="actionButtons" value="';
                    if ($row['adStatus'] == "disabled")
                        echo 'הצג מודעה בלוח" />';
                    else
                        echo 'הסתר מודעה מהלוח" />';
                    echo '
                    <input type="submit" name="deleteAd" value="מחק מודעה" class="deleteButton" />
                </form>
```

and here is the script to forward to the processing php file and writing some results on the current page:

```
    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#actionForm").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.post('/tests/process.php', $("#actionForm").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#resDiv').html(data);
                });
            }
        }});
            }); 
</script>
```

the processing php only writes data to the database and prints a confirm message.
here is the link to it:  http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29c4

I've inspected every single line of the code but still can't get why I see no message from the processing php...

any ideas?

thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. here is the full code of the initial php:  http://codeviewer.org/view/code:29c3

Comment: Use developers console in your browser to see what you get in the response.

Comment: Also there is a suitable class for jquery iframe-post ... take a look here http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html

Comment: Just a note that you shouldn't do this: `DELETE FROM ads WHERE adID = $adID` where `$adID` is a POST variable. That leaves you open to SQL injection. If somebody made a POST request with `anything OR x=x`, your database would suddenly vanish. You should sanitize your POST input like this: `$adID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adID']);` and then put quotes around $adID in `WHERE adID = '$adID'`

Comment: thanks, i just haven't reached the safety and security part of this project yet :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your javascript snippet at the end of your code is wrong. The submit handler must not be in the rules: {} block.

Try the following:

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#actionForm").validate({
            debug: false,
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.post('/tests/process.php', $("#actionForm").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#resDiv').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```